# CAB file installation within MSI

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project, cab

I have a CAB file which will do some registration within the IE,I need to make an MSI file that will be downloaded first then while installing it it should install the CAB file

I also have some actions while installing so I do override to install method with the other steps but with CAB I don't know I if I should install it using Process and CMD or there's a builtin way to do this !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI packages use their own CABs and are linked to them through the information stored in MSI database. So a MSI cannot install your custom CAB directly.

A solution is to insert your custom CAB in [Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367825%28VS.85%29.aspx) table. A custom action can then extract it and register it the way you want.

For extracting from Binary table a custom action needs the installation handle. So you need a win32 DLL or VBScript. You cannot use an installer class.

You can find a C++ DLL custom action tutorial here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx